# How to take SQL Server database backup using Jenkins daily?

Tags: sql-server, windows, jenkins

I've tried to take backup using Windows batch command. It's working, but I need to take automatic backups with different name for 7 days as `day1.bak`, `day2.bak`, ...

```
SQLCMD -S xx.xx.xxx.xx -U test -P xxxx 
       -Q "BACKUP  DATABASE test TO DISK='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\test4.bak'"
```

Is there is a Jenkins plugin to do this automatically?

Comment: Note that backup command will append the backup to the file.  If that's not what you want, use the INIT option in your backup command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set mydate=%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set mytime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

forfiles /P 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'  /S /M *.bak /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"  // Delete all file less than 7 days


sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [YourDataBaseName] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\%mydate%_%mytime%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'YourDataBaseName-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
```

> Note: filename equals date-time now by using both variable **mydate** & **mytime**

Comment: The database name should be included in the name of the backup file, not just the name of the backup inside the file.

Comment: you can add any characters  for file name but for unique fileName must add Date-Time like this `MyDataBase_%mydate%_%mytime%.bak`